# Python Curses numberpad causes program to exit

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-curses

I have this function that edits a file, and it is called with a curses.wrapper(). I am trying to add an option for number pad 0 which toggles an option. But every time I press anything on the number pad the program just immediately closes. I did try with both keypad(0) and keypad(1) and all that does is make the numbpad work for inputting numbers. I do believe it has something to do with so many if statements because I got this to work in a smaller program, but I want to make sure. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import curses
import sys,os

 def edit_existing(stdscr, Lines):

    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.refresh()
    curses.mousemask(1)
    #stdscr.keypad(0)
    #stdscr.nodelay(1)
    curses.raw()

    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()

    curses.start_color()
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_CYAN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)

    key, curs_x, curs_y, mouse_x, mouse_y, mouse_state, line_num, ows  = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1


    for line in Lines:
            temp = Lines[line_num]
            temp = temp.ljust(width)
            stdscr.addstr(line_num, 0, temp)
            Lines[line_num] = temp
            stdscr.refresh()
            line_num += 1

    empty_line = ''.ljust(width)

    while True:

            height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
            stdscr.addstr(height - 1, width - 8, "       ", curses.color_pair(1))
            stdscr.addstr(height - 1, width - ((len(str(key)) + 1 + 1)), str(key), curses.color_pair(1))

            if (curs_y not in Lines):
                    Lines[curs_y] = empty_line


            if (key == curses.KEY_RIGHT):
                    curs_x += 1
            elif (key == curses.KEY_LEFT):
                    curs_x -= 1
            elif (key == curses.KEY_DOWN):
                    curs_y += 1
            elif (key == curses.KEY_UP):
                    curs_y -= 1
            elif (key == 27):
                    break
            elif (key == curses.KEY_MOUSE):
                    _, curs_x, curs_y, _, mouse_state = curses.getmouse()
            elif (key == 32):
                    stdscr.insch(curs_y, curs_x, " ")

                    tempstring =  Lines[curs_y]
                    tempstring = list(tempstring)
                    tempstring.insert(curs_x, " ")
                    Lines[curs_y] = "".join(tempstring)

                    curs_x += 1
            elif (key == 10):
                    stdscr.insertln()
                    curs_x = 0
                    curs_y += 1
            elif (key == curses.KEY_BACKSPACE):
                    curs_x -= 1
                    if (curs_x != -1):
                            stdscr.delch(curs_y, curs_x)
                            tempstring =  Lines[curs_y]
                            tempstring = list(tempstring)
                            del tempstring[curs_x]
                            Lines[curs_y] = "".join(tempstring)
            elif (key == 330):
                    stdscr.addstr(curs_y, curs_x, " ")

                    tempstring =  Lines[curs_y]
                    tempstring = list(tempstring)
                    tempstring[curs_x] = " "
                    Lines[curs_y] = "".join(tempstring)

            elif (key != 0):

                    if (ows == 1):
                            stdscr.addstr(curs_y, curs_x, chr(key))

                            tempstring =  Lines[curs_y]
                            tempstring = list(tempstring)
                            tempstring[curs_x] = chr(key)
                            Lines[curs_y] = "".join(tempstring)
                    else:
                            stdscr.insch(curs_y, curs_x, chr(key))

                            tempstring =  Lines[curs_y]
                            tempstring = list(tempstring)
                            tempstring.insert(curs_x, chr(key))
                            Lines[curs_y] = "".join(tempstring)

                    curs_x += 1

            if (curs_x >= width):
                    curs_y += 1
                    curs_x = 0
            elif (curs_x < 0):
                    curs_x = 0
                    if (curs_y > 0):
                            curs_y -= 1

            if (curs_y >= height):
                    curs_y = height - 1
            elif (curs_y < 0):
                    curs_y = 0


            stdscr.move(curs_y, curs_x)
            stdscr.refresh()

            key = stdscr.getch()

            if (key == 112):
                    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "NUM0 PRESSED")


    stdscr.refresh()
    curses.endwin()

    return Lines

    stdscr.refresh()
    curses.endwin()
```